# Strange doctrine results array structure if I pass in DQL query three times join with the same related entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I get a strange result array structure

this is my DQL query and php code on symfony platform:

```
    $params = array();

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT c1 as cat1, c2 as cat2, c3 as cat3, count(s.id) as tot
            FROM Priatdru\PolyglotBundle\Entity\SearchQuery s
            INNER JOIN ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle:Category c1 WITH s.category1 = c1.id
            INNER JOIN ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle:Category c2 WITH s.category2 = c2.id
            LEFT  JOIN ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle:Category c3 WITH s.category3 = c3.id
            WHERE s.sessionId != :session_id
            AND (
              (s.category1 = :category1 AND s.category2 IS NOT NULL)
              OR s.category2 = :category1
              OR s.category3 = :category1
              )
            GROUP BY cat1,cat2,cat3
            ORDER BY tot ASC
        ');

    $params['session_id'] = $session_id;
    $params['category1'] = $category1;
    $query->setParameters($params);

   return $query->getResult();
```

var_dump:

```
  array (size=10)
    0 => 
      array (size=1)
        'cat1' => 
          object(Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[1309]
            protected 'id' => int 8755
                ...
            private 'nameEn' => string 'French' (length=6)
            private 'nameFr' => string 'Français' (length=9)
            private 'nameIt' => string 'Francese' (length=8)
            private 'nameDe' => string 'Französisch' (length=12)
            private 'nameEs' => string 'Francés' (length=8)
            private 'slugEn' => string 'french' (length=6)
            private 'slugFr' => string 'francais' (length=8)
            private 'slugIt' => string 'francese' (length=8)
            private 'slugDe' => string 'franzosisch' (length=11)
            private 'slugEs' => string 'frances' (length=7)
            protected 'name' => string 'fr' (length=2)
            protected 'slug' => string 'french' (length=6)
            protected 'enabled' => boolean true
            protected 'description' => string 'French' (length=6)
            protected 'createdAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[1306]
                ...
            protected 'updatedAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[1307]
                ...
            protected 'position' => null
            protected 'children' => 
              object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[1464]
                ...
            protected 'parent' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[1540]
                ...
            protected 'media' => null
            protected 'context' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Context)[1518]
                ...
    1 => 
      array (size=1)
        'cat2' => 
          object(Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[2390]
            protected 'id' => int 8821
                ...
            private 'nameEn' => string 'Italian' (length=7)
            private 'nameFr' => string 'Italien' (length=7)
            private 'nameIt' => string 'Italiano' (length=8)
            private 'nameDe' => string 'Italienisch' (length=11)
            private 'nameEs' => string 'Italiano' (length=8)
            private 'slugEn' => string 'italian' (length=7)
            private 'slugFr' => string 'italien' (length=7)
            private 'slugIt' => string 'italiano' (length=8)
            private 'slugDe' => string 'italienisch' (length=11)
            private 'slugEs' => string 'italiano' (length=8)
            protected 'name' => string 'it' (length=2)
            protected 'slug' => string 'italian' (length=7)
            protected 'enabled' => boolean true
            protected 'description' => string 'Italian' (length=7)
            protected 'createdAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[2312]
                ...
            protected 'updatedAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[2396]
                ...
            protected 'position' => null
            protected 'children' => 
              object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[2376]
                ...
            protected 'parent' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[1540]
                ...
            protected 'media' => null
            protected 'context' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Context)[1518]
                ...
    2 => 
      array (size=2)
        'cat3' => null
        'tot' => string '2' (length=1)
    3 => 
      array (size=1)
        'cat1' => 
          object(Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[2390]
            protected 'id' => int 8821
                ...
            private 'nameEn' => string 'Italian' (length=7)
            private 'nameFr' => string 'Italien' (length=7)
            private 'nameIt' => string 'Italiano' (length=8)
            private 'nameDe' => string 'Italienisch' (length=11)
            private 'nameEs' => string 'Italiano' (length=8)
            private 'slugEn' => string 'italian' (length=7)
            private 'slugFr' => string 'italien' (length=7)
            private 'slugIt' => string 'italiano' (length=8)
            private 'slugDe' => string 'italienisch' (length=11)
            private 'slugEs' => string 'italiano' (length=8)
            protected 'name' => string 'it' (length=2)
            protected 'slug' => string 'italian' (length=7)
            protected 'enabled' => boolean true
            protected 'description' => string 'Italian' (length=7)
            protected 'createdAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[2312]
                ...
            protected 'updatedAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[2396]
                ...
            protected 'position' => null
            protected 'children' => 
              object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[2376]
                ...
            protected 'parent' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[1540]
                ...
            protected 'media' => null
            protected 'context' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Context)[1518]
                ...
    4 => 
      array (size=1)
        'cat2' => 
          object(Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[1309]
            protected 'id' => int 8755
                ...
            private 'nameEn' => string 'French' (length=6)
            private 'nameFr' => string 'Français' (length=9)
            private 'nameIt' => string 'Francese' (length=8)
            private 'nameDe' => string 'Französisch' (length=12)
            private 'nameEs' => string 'Francés' (length=8)
            private 'slugEn' => string 'french' (length=6)
            private 'slugFr' => string 'francais' (length=8)
            private 'slugIt' => string 'francese' (length=8)
            private 'slugDe' => string 'franzosisch' (length=11)
            private 'slugEs' => string 'frances' (length=7)
            protected 'name' => string 'fr' (length=2)
            protected 'slug' => string 'french' (length=6)
            protected 'enabled' => boolean true
            protected 'description' => string 'French' (length=6)
            protected 'createdAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[1306]
                ...
            protected 'updatedAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[1307]
                ...
            protected 'position' => null
            protected 'children' => 
              object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[1464]
                ...
            protected 'parent' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[1540]
                ...
            protected 'media' => null
            protected 'context' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Context)[1518]
                ...
    5 => 
      array (size=2)
        'cat3' => null
        'tot' => string '5' (length=1)
    6 => 
      array (size=1)
        'cat2' => 
          object(Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[2397]
            protected 'id' => int 8736
                ...
            private 'nameEn' => string 'Spanish' (length=7)
            private 'nameFr' => string 'Espagnol' (length=8)
            private 'nameIt' => string 'Spagnolo' (length=8)
            private 'nameDe' => string 'Spanisch' (length=8)
            private 'nameEs' => string 'Español' (length=8)
            private 'slugEn' => string 'spanish' (length=7)
            private 'slugFr' => string 'espagnol' (length=8)
            private 'slugIt' => string 'spagnolo' (length=8)
            private 'slugDe' => string 'spanisch' (length=8)
            private 'slugEs' => string 'espanol' (length=7)
            protected 'name' => string 'es' (length=2)
            protected 'slug' => string 'spanish' (length=7)
            protected 'enabled' => boolean true
            protected 'description' => string 'Spanish' (length=7)
            protected 'createdAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[2335]
                ...
            protected 'updatedAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[2330]
                ...
            protected 'position' => null
            protected 'children' => 
              object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[2370]
                ...
            protected 'parent' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[1540]
                ...
            protected 'media' => null
            protected 'context' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Context)[1518]
                ...
    7 => 
      array (size=2)
        'cat3' => null
        'tot' => string '5' (length=1)
    8 => 
      array (size=1)
        'cat1' => 
          object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[1671]
            public '__initializer__' => null
            public '__cloner__' => null
            public '__isInitialized__' => boolean true
            protected 'id' => int 8616
                ...
            private 'nameEn' (Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category) => string 'English' (length=7)
            private 'nameFr' (Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category) => string 'Anglais' (length=7)
            private 'nameIt' (Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category) => string 'Inglese' (length=7)
            private 'nameDe' (Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category) => string 'Englisch' (length=8)
            private 'nameEs' (Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category) => string 'Inglés' (length=7)
            private 'slugEn' (Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category) => string 'english' (length=7)
            private 'slugFr' (Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category) => string 'anglais' (length=7)
            private 'slugIt' (Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category) => string 'inglese' (length=7)
            private 'slugDe' (Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category) => string 'englisch' (length=8)
            private 'slugEs' (Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category) => string 'ingles' (length=6)
            protected 'name' => string 'en' (length=2)
            protected 'slug' => string 'english' (length=7)
            protected 'enabled' => boolean true
            protected 'description' => string 'English' (length=7)
            protected 'createdAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[2394]
                ...
            protected 'updatedAt' => 
              object(DateTime)[2399]
                ...
            protected 'position' => null
            protected 'children' => 
              object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[2326]
                ...
            protected 'parent' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category)[1540]
                ...
            protected 'media' => null
            protected 'context' => 
              object(Proxies\__CG__\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Context)[1518]
                ...
    9 => 
      array (size=2)
        'cat3' => null
        'tot' => string '17' (length=2)
```

When I change the select line in the DQL query :

```
  SELECT c1.name as cat1, c2.name as cat2, c3.name as cat3, count(s.id) as tot
```

now structure array is what I EXPECT :
var_dump:

```
  array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'cat1' => string 'fr' (length=2)
          'cat2' => string 'it' (length=2)
          'cat3' => null
          'tot' => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'cat1' => string 'fr' (length=2)
          'cat2' => string 'es' (length=2)
          'cat3' => null
          'tot' => string '5' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'cat1' => string 'it' (length=2)
          'cat2' => string 'fr' (length=2)
          'cat3' => null
          'tot' => string '5' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=4)
          'cat1' => string 'en' (length=2)
          'cat2' => string 'fr' (length=2)
          'cat3' => null
          'tot' => string '17' (length=2)
```

If someone had already similar problems please lets share informations.
Thanks all community in advance!
regards

Comment: Could you please be more clear on what you expect and what you get ?

Comment: I d like to get an array with elements that contain Category object to easier manage each element as single line result. Like this:
        0 => 
               array (size=4)
                   'cat1' => (Object Category)
                   'cat2' => (Object Category)
                   'cat3' => null
                   'tot' => string '2' (length=1)
       1 => 
              array (size=4)
..... ....

Answer (score 1):

I hope i can help you clearing out a couple of thing.

In the first example your DQL query it's working *with the entity*:

```
SELECT c1 as cat1, c2 as cat2, c3 as cat3
```

as you can see with **c1 as cat1** the computed result-set will be of ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle:Category type and, of course, all other joined relation will be presented aswell. For all intent and purpose you are dealing with objects here.

in the second example you provided:

```
SELECT c1.name as cat1, c2.name as cat2, c3.name as cat3, count(s.id) as tot
```

as you can see you are working with the entity field (**c1.name**), forcing an *ArrayHydration* on the result.

---

If you want to keep your first approach make sure to impose a proper hydration:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM CmsUser u');
$users = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

for further reference check [this page.](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

---

**EDIT:**

As in this case you're doing a very specific extraction it's common practice to drop the object relation altogether and move to an array approach. You can make use of a more specific select **1.name** as you stated in the second example;

should the need arise to retrive the object you may consider adding the identifier to the extraction **c1.id** and and *lazly* fetch-it from a repository (findBy).

hope it helps,

regards.

Comment: Thank for answer! The hydratation doesn't change my problem. I'd expect in each element of result array (for the first select) to have elements composed like the follow =>
0 => array (size=4) 
   'cat1' => (Object Category) 
   'cat2' => (Object Category) 
   'cat3' => null 
   'tot' => string '2' (length=1)

Comment: Thank you very much! I just wanted to avoid the findBy, but if is the only solution (?) I'll try to put in select all fields that I need from Category and that's it. Thanks again :)